# Como criar mensagens utilizando FutureDelayed?

Tags: flutter

Pessoal sou novo com a linguagem flutter e estou com o seguinte problema.
Conforme a imagem abaixo o cliente pediu que no lugar de carregar ficasse passando 3 mensagens, como se fosse tipo um slide.
Como faço isso no flutter ou qual técnica posso utilizar para chegar nesse resultado na tela de um splash?
Exemplo: X segundos [Mensagem A], Y segundos [Mensagm b] e assim vai...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa mensagem eu criei dentro de um expand

```
Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
                Text("                    Carregando... \n Aguarde um momento por favor!", style: Style.H5,),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Transforma a tela em um StateFullWidget, usa SetState() para redesenhar a tela e troca as mensagens. Ai o controlador e o timer vai depender da sua programação.

Comment: Eu tive que criar um cara para dar x segundo ai ele pular para próxima tela seria mais ou menos dessa forma?

 @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())));
  }

Comment: Não faz tudo na mesma tela, opcao = 1; depois de 3 segundos opcao = 2; depois opcao = 3;  e a cada opcao voce escreve algo diferente, usar StateFullWidget para mudar o state da tela

Comment: Pode dar bom usando um stream

Comment: Se a gente te responder vamos ganhar uns 10% do valor que o cliente te pagar xD?? Faça igual o @GabrielLocalhost disse, transforme sua tela em um `StatefulWidget`, crie uma lista com os textos que quer e no _Timer_, você não muda de tela, mas sim você faz `setState(() count++)` e para exibir o texto tu faz `Text(minhaList[count])`